# SQL and Excel Import

Tags: asp.net, sql, null

Please read my post if you have enough time,

I have requirement, I have a table in which there is column of Type DateTime, It should be accept null values.

When this table data is being display in ASPX Page, I have an option to export the data into EXCEL 2003 Spread Sheet.

If there is a null value for a record, When I export the Data into Excel Sheet, This field is not being Exported.

If I don't check for a null Value in The Stored procedure while Loading Data into Excel Spreadsheet, It pushes 1/1/1990 by default for all null Values into excel sheet.

What is best way for me to finsih this task where I have to replace the Null Date Value with a Empty Date and can be exported to excel sheet without 1/1/1990.

If anyone who is kind enough to answer this question , Please ask me for more information.

Thank You
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 0):

Excel treats null dates as 1/1/1990.  When you run the query to extract the information, I'd suggest using a CASE to handle the date.

```
Select 
    (CASE WHEN myDate IS NULL then '' ELSE Convert(Varchar(10), myDate, 101) END) as myDate
```